# Remove property by value from object

Tags: javascript

I have a simple object like this:

```
var obj = {
    "option1": "item1",
    "option2": "item2",
    "option3": "item3"
};
```

For adding a new property to the object I'm using the following code:

```
obj[this.value] = this.innerHTML;

// this.innerHTML is used just because I'm adding the value I get from a DOM element
```

Is there a function that can help me remove a property from the object, that receives as a parameter the value of the key-value pair?

For example `removeItem('item3');`.

Comment: The built-in [delete keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)?

Comment: Can I refer to value insted of the key?

Comment: Not natively, you would have to write your own function that would iterate through all of the object's properties looking for your desired value, and `delete` the property(-ies) whose value match the value you're looking for.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That would probably be `delete` :

```
delete obj['option1'];
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xfDye/)

To do it by value, you'd do something like :

```
function deleteByVal(val) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj[key] == val) delete obj[key];
    }
}

deleteByVal('item1');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xfDye/1/)

Comment: Can I remove the element that has value equal to item1 ?

Comment: @Joseph82 Note that the function above will delete multiple properties with the same value. Also, it loosely checks type with `==` as opposed to `===`. None of this is bad or wrong, it just depends upon what you want/need.

Comment: Ok. I'm sure my values are all different.

Answer (score 2):

This question has been answered correctly but there is just one thing I want to add:

You should write a pure function for this solution. That is a function that does not require your object to be defined in the global scope.

so:

```
const deleteObjectItemByValue = (Obj, val) => {
    for (var key in Obj) {
        if (Obj[key] == val) {
            delete Obj[key];
            return Obj;
        }
    }
};
```

usage: `deleteObjectItemByValue(yourObj, val);`
This is a pure function that does not have side effects i.e mutate anything in its outer environment and does not depend on any global variable for its operation.

Answer (score -1):

Like this-

`delete obj["option1"];` Or `delete obj.option1;`

Comment: You misinterpreted the question. The question asks how to delete key/value pairs selecting by VALUE, not by key. Please consider deleting or editing your answer.