# Delete item from associate array using value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a java script array. I want to remove specific item from array using value. I can not remove by key because i am making dynamic functionality and there i have only value so i have to remove specific item from  using value.

```
var arr =   Array();
arr['a']    =   123;
arr['b']    =   234;
arr['c']    =   345;
arr['d']    =   456;
arr['e']    =   567;
```

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev The answers there use `splice()`, which only works for numeric arrays. This question is actually about object properties.

Comment: You really confused lots of answerers by calling this an array. It's an object. In JS, arrays are only indexed using integers. When you use strings, they're object properties.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove property by value from object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134386/remove-property-by-value-from-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have repeated values you wish to delete:

```
var arr =   Array();
arr['a']    =   123;
arr['b']    =   234;
arr['c']    =   345;
arr['d']    =   456;
arr['e']    =   567;

function removeEl(arr,val){
    for (var i in arr){
        if(arr[i]==val){
            delete arr[i];
        }
    }
}
removeEl(arr,234)
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be treating JavaScript arrays as associative arrays, however, this isn't how arrays in JavaScript work. With the format your data is taking, I would suggest having them stored as an object:

```
var obj = {
   "a": 123,
   "b": 234,
   "c": 345,
   "d": 456,
   "e": 567
};
```

You can then iterate and remove using this function:

```
function removeByValue(object, value) {
   for (var e in object) {
      if (object[e] === value) {
         delete object[e];
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you are creating an `array`, then treating it like an `object`.

Your JavaScript life will be MUCH easier if you pretend that arrays can only take `integer` properties.[1]

So, what you really mean to do is this:

```
var obj =   {};
obj['a']    =   123;
obj['b']    =   234;
obj['c']    =   345;
obj['d']    =   456;
obj['e']    =   567;
```

Or, in object literal format:

```
var obj =   {
  a:   123,
  b:   234,
  c:   345,
  d:   456,
  e:   567
};
```

To delete a `property` from an `object`, simply use the `delete` keyword:

```
delete obj.b;
```

[1] Technically, arrays are also objects -- but arrays are special-purpose objects.

Answer (score 0):

`.indexOf` won't work because it isn't an array so you should find and remove this value manually

```
var arr =   Array();
arr['a']    =   123;
arr['b']    =   234;
arr['c']    =   345;
arr['d']    =   456;
arr['e']    =   567;

var result={};
var value_to_remove = 123;
for(key in arr){
    if(arr[key]!=value_to_remove)
        result[key] = arr[key];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In PHP use `array_search` to find key then  use  `unset()` destroys the specified variables.

**edited**

in Jquery :

to find index use `inArray`  `jQuery.inArray( "123", arr )`

and to unset use `delete`

```
delete arr.index;
```

Comment: But how to find the element to unset?

Comment: The question is about Javascript, not PHP.